# How to implement logic for BigDecimal rendering in freemarker?

Tags: java, freemarker

I have a lot of freemarker templates. For all this templates I want my own logic for the rendering of [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) types.

Basically I need a renderer that makes sure every BigDecimal beeing rendered with as many decimal places as its scale.

Since I have a lot of templates and a lot of BigDeciamls with different scale, I'd prefer a transparent solution. If possible I'd like to avoid to call special format functions in the templates.

Any ideas which freemarker API I should use for this? I looked into [`TemplateModel`](http://freemarker.org/docs/api/freemarker/template/TemplateModel.html) but could not find any formatting functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pluggable number (and date/time) formatters is a planned feature for 2.3.24 (release candidate expected at the end of this month, stable around the end of September). Until that, the global number formatting options are limited to what `java.text.DecimalFormat` can do.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer! Is there a way to plug in my own subclass of `java.text.DecimalFormat`?

Comment: No, it's hardwired in 2.3.23 and before. I suggest you just put in your own `DecimalFormat` subclass by modifying the source code, and then later it will be doable in 2.3.24 without that (hopefully).